# How to estimate end time of method in WinForms to properly inform user about predicted time of finish?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, c#-3.0

I've got some timers that measure the time to execute code.

```
 DateTime startTimeFunctionTotal = DateTime.Now;
     for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++) {
         DateTime startTimeFunction = DateTime.Now;
         //some code here

          DateTime stopTimeFunction = DateTime.Now;
          TimeSpan durationTimeFunction = stopTimeFunction - startTimeFunction ;

 }
 DateTime stopTimeFunctionTotal = DateTime.Now;
 TimeSpan durationTimeFunctionTotal = stopTimeFunctionTotal - startTimeFunctionTotal ;
```

It's allowed (even better) if the predicted time changes according to more data (every loop there is more data so prediction should be more accurate).

I would like to give user a predicted time of finish (both time like 15 minutes, and 10:56).

Comment: Exactly what is your question here?

Comment: My question was how to do math on TimeSpans, and DateTimes to make it display finish time and time left properly.

Comment: If you ever figure out how to accurately predict the time something finishes, please sell this solution to Microsoft, so we can end this: http://xkcd.com/612/

Comment: Ye i figured it's same thing, still it gives rough estimate what you can expect :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each action in your for statement takes roughly the same amount of time:

```
List<TimeSpan> timeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();
for(int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
{
    Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    //do stuff
    timeSpans.Add(watch.Elapsed);
    long ticksLeft = timeSpans.Sum(ts => ts.Ticks) * (array.Count - i) / timeSpans.Count;
    Console.WriteLine("Left: " + new TimeSpan(ticksLeft));
    Console.WriteLine("Finished in: " + 
        DateTime.Now.AddTicks(ticksLeft));
}
```

To go with the median use:

```
long ticksLeft = timeSpans.OrderBy(ts => ts.Ticks)
    .ElementAt(timeSpans.Count / 2).Ticks * (array.Count - i);
```

Comment: It seems very good. What would you propose if there's a bit more differences in time (like 1 sec here, 5 secs there, 3 secs here). It has a bit of problem to make it time accurately. I know estimation is estimation but maybe it could be tweaked a bit.

Comment: @MadBoy: You could go with the median. as suggested by nobugz, I will update my answer with it. If this doesn't work, you need to say how many transactions and how long it should take, and I'll see if I can do something about throwing out values. But these things will likely vary widely by machine.

Comment: THanks. But are you sure median one is correct? Errors out on me. Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan' and 'int'

Comment: @MadBoy: Not my day today with bugs, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an auto-correcting guess, as long as there are sufficient operations that each can be timed individually and each take roughly the same amount of time.  Start out with a guess and multiply by the number of operations to perform.  Measure the time of the next operation and add that to a list.  Make a new guess by taking the average of the times in this list and multiply that by the number of operations left.

Your guess will get more accurate as you get more timing samples.  And your progress bar will always reach 100% (+/- a wee bit).  Taking the median instead of the average is better, it eliminates outliers due to sudden activity on your machine by other processes.  And you'll want to throw out old measurements in the list, keeping only 10 to 20 is enough.  Keep more samples if the operation time is more variable.

Comment: Care to show an example how to aproach this? The biggest problem i have with Math on this, how to divide, multiply etc on TimeSpans and Dates.

Comment: Just make your guess an int or long, the number of milliseconds or microseconds per operation.  Convert to TimeSpan only in the UI code.

Comment: Would you consider Yuriy example as good one? It seems to be a bit too much off (even with 1000 samples).

Comment: @madboy - he doesn't handle Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks properly, its unit (1/Frequency) is not the same as that of TimeSpan.Ticks (100 nsec).

Comment: @nobugz: Thanks, corrected. Looks like I still need Intellisense.

Comment: Things may vary for me because i use Database and each call gets sometimes 5 transactions and sometimes 30 then do the counting on that. Having around 1200 calls to database makes it vary a lot :-) Especially on the beginning when transactions are small and take less then a second and later on there are big guns which take up to 10 sec each. But i guess my users will just have to get used to term estimation isn't the right time it will finish :)

Comment: Time isn't good for feedback then.  Why don't you just report the number of operations left to be performed...

Comment: I do that. I give user about 10 diffrent measures saying how long last count took, which client it was, which day, which type was counted etc. How many loops are total, how many loops already passed, but rough estimation (come back in 15 minutes) should give them better overview.

Answer (score 1):

To get a better representation of timing for code performance (in a nice [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)) have a look at the [`System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

It works like you would expect: `Start()` to begin timing, `Stop()` to stop. Read `Elapsed` to get a `TimeSpan` of the time taken, or `ElapsedTicks` for the most accurate measurement (a `TimeSpan.Ticks` = 1.0 x 10<sup>-9</sup> sec, or 100 nano-sec; `ElapsedTicks` is variable and is relative to the `StopWatch.Frequency` of 1-sec/value).